# "I can change the way I look at it" translation

Tags: translation, phrase

The context is: “I cannot change the way I look but I can change the way I look at it.” How could you translate the last part?

My proposal would be “Ich kann es nicht ändern wie ich aussehe, aber ich kann es ändern wie ich darin aussehe.” However this sounds just not right and the meaning isn't clear.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you translate the first part? (The choice of words for the second depends on it.)

Comment: “Ich kann es nicht ändern, wie ich aussehe”. But then when I try to continue it sounds strage: “Aber ich kann es ändern, wie ich damit aussehe”. It just doesn't fit.

Comment: Have you tried? If so, it's tradition (almost rule) to show that you have. Otherwise it looks like you're just using us a translators.

Comment: Yes sorry I really forgot to post my tries in the answer, that's why I answered it in the comments. I'll edit it, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @c.p. not *almost*. it is **rule** that you **have to** provide translation attempts or research effort in translation questions.

Comment: @TimWagner Next time, perhaps you should explain the meaning of your expression in the question. It will make it easier to translate as the meaning will be clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a very loose translation attempt to capture the meaning in a comparably short phrase:

> Meine Haut kann ich nicht ändern, wie ich mich darin fühle aber schon.

Comment: Nice, I'd take out the "zwar" though... it feels "fillerish" and takes away some punch

Comment: @Emanuel: it's the *zwar...aber* construct I was using here.

Comment: @Takkat... I know, but "zwar" can live just fine without the "zwar". The "zwar" just spoils us on the punch line.

Comment: @Emanuel That's true for the sake of punching... Thanks for pointing to that :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my take on it:

1) Ich kann mein Aussehen nicht ändern, aber meine Betrachtungsweise (dessen).

2) Ich kann nicht ändern, wie ich aussehe, jedoch was ich davon denke.

Anyway, it's not as pwetty as in English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid that's not what I meant. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Here is an example of what I mean. When you cut your hair, you cannot change the way you look, but you can change the way you look at it, meaning you can look different in your own skin.

Comment: Ich kann nicht (mehr) ändern, wie ich aussehe, jedoch wie ich damit umgehe.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks for that answer